# Basement support post stabilization if the foundation is sinking and has been stabilized with steel push piers

Tags: foundation

I'm looking at buying a house with a foundation that has been stabilized following a drought that caused it to sink.

Steel push piers were installed all around the foundation. During the works, the interior of the house moved and the basement slab broke at a few places.

It made me wonder, should the load bearing posts (there appears to be 3 inside the middle wall in the basement) be stabilized? Is it common to stabilize the perimeter, but not the inside?

I get that these poles are probably under a lot less stress than the perimeter. I also understand every house and soil are different. I'm just wondering what is usually done.

Anyone with experience?

Thanks!